# when Sharepoint list has white spaces

Tags: web-part, custom

In my custom web part, I am refering to the list name to build a string url. The list name has white spaces.
How do I handle it?

string url = relaticveaddressofweb = "List/list%20Name"?

Is the above correct?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, the %20 will do it. Your URL however should be lists/ not list/

Comment: ok good, if this answer is correct, please make sure to mark it as so for other people ;)

Comment: I need to mark this question as answered

Comment: please do ;) I think there is a green checkmark right up there

Comment: There should be a checkmark, sorry, grey, not green, to the left of my answer, below the chevrons http://screencast.com/t/Cyfpjyxw1r